# What is a stock split (reverse split)?

Tags: stocks, stock-split

In the picture below, Citigroup's stock split 1 to 10. My guess is this means that everyone who had 1 share now has 10 shares? This can't be right though, because the value of the stock after the split should be 1/10th of the value prior to the split. Somebody help me out here.

[image: Google finance chart of Citigroup for January 2011 - April 2012]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It was actually a reverse split meaning that every 10 shares you had became 1 share and the price should be 10x higher. - [Citigroup in reverse split](http://money.cnn.com/2011/03/21/news/companies/citigroup_reverse_stock_split/index.htm)

The chart just accounts for the split. The big dip is Googles way of showing from what price it split from. If you remember before the split the stock was trading around $4-$5 after the reverse split the stock became 10x higher.

Just to clear it up a 1:2(1 for 2) split would mean you get 1 share for every 2 shares you have. This is known as a reverse split.

A 2:1(2 for 1) split means you get 2 shares for every 1 share you have.

The first number represents the amount of shares you will receive and the second number represents how many shares you will be giving up.

Comment: just a note...I don't think google shows that drop intentionally, I think there is just some problem with there stock price aggregator.  The flag is on there to represent the split.

Comment: @Pablitorun that's a possibility that could just be an error. On my chart from ameritrade it does not show the dip.